# load cakephp model into related controller

Tags: model, controller, cakephp-2.0

I have a cakephp2 project wher I have a user and different possible roles (admin, writer, moderator).  Each role has its own Model.  When the user logs in I check if the user is in a role  and redirect to the controller for the role.  But I can't seem to load the Model assosiated with the user.

```
$user = $this->Auth->user();
if($user['role'] == 'writer'){
  $writer = $this->Writer->findByUser_id($user['id']);
  $writerID = $writer['id'];
  # redirect and such here
}
```

Cake gives an error on the third line saying that

```
Error: Call to a member function findByUser_id() on a non-object
```

I have the following in the User model

```
public $hasOne = 'Writer';
```

and this in the Writer model

```
public $belongsTo = 'User';
```

I know this must be super simple but I can't seem to figure out how to get the Writer model into my controller.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using that find in controller then you will have to use chaining

```
$this->User->Writer->findByUserId($id);
```

If it's in the model then you are fine with the chaining. Other thing you might have noticed is "**UserId** which applies to **user_id** in the table.

Additionally, you can use recursive or containable to get associated results from Writer and Moderator

If in User's controller

```
$this->User->Behaviors->attach('Containable');

$this->User->contain(array('Writer'));
//do ur find
```

As a best practice try keeping these find's in the Model layer. In the model layer you will skip the name of model from the chains.

Comment: Thanks.  I found that in this case I could also use $user['Writer']['id']